# Tweepy python code returns KeyError on 'media' entity when tweet does not contain image

Tags: python, api, twitter, entities, tweepy

Hi people of StackOverflow

I am relatively new to Tweepy/Twitter API and am having a few issues getting it to return the URL's for images.

Basically, I have written a snippet of code that searches for tweets against a particular hashtag, then returns image URL entities that exist in the tweets. I am hitting an issue however when a tweet is returned that does not have any media in it. Error shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./tweepyTest.py", line 18, in <module>
for image in  tweet.entities['media']:
KeyError: 'media'
```

Below is my code:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#hashtag",count=5,include_entities=True).items(5):
        #print tweet.text
        for image in  tweet.entities['media']:
            print image['media_url']
```

I am guessing I need to encase the for loop in some kind of if statement, however I am struggling to get my head around how.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I think I might have found a solution, however i'm not sure it is particularly elegant.....using a try/except.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#hashtag",count=5,include_entities=True).items(5):
    #print tweet.text
    try:
            for image in  tweet.entities['media']:
                    print image['media_url']
    except KeyError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check for the existence of the key:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#hashtag",count=5,include_entities=True).items(5):
    #print tweet.text
    if 'media' in tweet.entities:
        for image in  tweet.entities['media']:
            print image['media_url']
```

Or get an empty list if there is no such key:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#hashtag",count=5,include_entities=True).items(5):
    #print tweet.text
    for image in  tweet.entities.get('media', []):
        print image['media_url']
```

Comment: can you explain how  `tweet.entities.get('media', [])` works ?? little confused with it and `tweet.entities['media']`

Comment: @KrishanuKonar - `tweet.entities` is a dictionary. Dictionaries have [a get() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) which returns the value of the requested key if it exists, or the default value given if the key does not exist. So `tweet.entities.get('media', [])` returns the list of media items if it exists, or an empty list if it doesn't exist. `tweet.entities['media']` works fine if the `media` key exists, but will raise a `KeyError` exception if it doesn't.